# Retrieve value from xml using linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML data

```
<Address Location="ABC">
   <Add Location="XYZ1" street="street1"  />
   <Add Location="VZC" street="street1" />
</Address>
```

I want to find out the value of `<add> --> street`  which is `street1`

I have tried it as below, not getting the result

```
var q = from res in xmlDoc.Descendants("Address")
        where res.Attribute("Location").Value == "ABC"
              && res.Element("Add").Attribute("Location").Value == "VZC"
        select new
               {
                  streetadd= res.Element("Add").Attribute("street").Value,
               };
```

Please someone suggest how to check the condition for child element in this case.

Comment: There is no problem with the query, it is working fine and also return result street1 , what do you want it to return ?

Comment: What conditions you want to check?

Comment: I want the Details of the stress whose Address Location="ABC" & Add Location="VZC"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var query = from res in xmlDoc.Descendants("Address")
                                where res.Attribute("Location").Value == "ABC"
                                from child in res.Elements("Add")
                                where child.Attribute("Location").Value == "VZC"
                                select new
                                {
                                    streetadd = child.Attribute("street").Value
                                };
```